# ImageButton onclick in PagerAdapter. Need to go to another class/XML file. ERROR

Tags: java, android, xml

Been researching around this for a while and can't seem to find any solutions. 
I have a 5 images that is in a PagerLayout swipe format. 
What I want to do is upon clicking an image, I want to go to another XML file/class.

Code: (I've commented out methods I have tried.)

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.chestpress,R.drawable.deadlift,R.drawable.squat,R.drawable.pullups,R.drawable.dips};
    private Context ctx; //Gets the context of a current state or application. Tells program what is going on somewhere else.
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;  //USed to instantiate layout XML files to View Objct.
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String[] names = {"Dumbell Press","Deadlift","Squats","Pullups","Tricep Dips"};
    public ImageView imageView;
    Activity activity;
    View views = null;


    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_resources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view==(LinearLayout)o;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
        imageView = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        TextView textView = (TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        textView.setText(names[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Log.d("Exercise","Dumbell Press");
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MyActivity.class);
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(CustomSwipeAdapter.this,MyActivity.class);
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
                    //views = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null);
                    //context.startActivity(intent);
                    //MyActivity koo = new MyActivity(); (Tried just instantiating another class (Im so lost) 

                }
                if(position == 1){
                    Log.d("Exercise","Deadlift!");
                }
                if(position == 2){
                    Log.d("Exercise","Squats");
                }
            }
        });

        return item_view;
    }




    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Very new android/java programmer. Thanks for reading.

Comment: do you get an Error... or something else ? does the other activity declared in the Manifest please write more info..

Comment: So for all the intents I get errors.  for the views code nothing happens. The manifest code is fine. I just need to find a way to go to another class with the onclick method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CustomSwipeAdapter.this.ctx, MyActivity.class);
CustomSwipeAdapter.this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Also make sure to pass the correct context to your Adapter constructor. The context you will pass can be the activity itself.

So, on your Activity, when you need to create a new adapter, do it like:

```
CustomSwipeAdapter myAdapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);
```

Where `this` is the Activity on which you are creating the adapter.
If you need to create the adapter inside a fragment, just get the activity with:

```
MyFragment.getActivity();
```

Lastly, if you are wondering: "why does that work? It expects a Context and I'm passing an activity!".

Here's a short answer:

> Activity inherits context. Thus, if you are in an activity, you only
>   need to pass itself to use the context. It also contains a pointer to
>   getBaseContext(). You might occasionally need to reference that, if
>   you need the entire application context, but most likely you won't for
>   a while.

Hope this helps.
Let me know if you get any more errors (don't forget to post your logcat so we can help you better).

Comment: Thanks very much this did it. Thanks for the extra explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

What you should ideally be doing is this,

1: Create an interface call it `swipeAdapterCallback` or something, declare a method for handling the onClick

2: Make sure you get the swipeAdapterCallback instance in the constructor.

3: Then all you have to do is invoke the onClick method in the callback instance.

I've posted the adapter code here:

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.chestpress, R.drawable.deadlift, R.drawable.squat, R.drawable.pullups, R.drawable.dips};
    private Context ctx; //Gets the context of a current state or application. Tells program what is going on somewhere else.
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;  //USed to instantiate layout XML files to View Objct.
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String[] names = {"Dumbell Press", "Deadlift", "Squats", "Pullups", "Tricep Dips"};
    public ImageView imageView;
    Activity activity;
    View views = null;
    private swipeAdapterCallback mCallback;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx,swipeAdapterCallback callback) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_resources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == (LinearLayout) o;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        TextView textView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
        textView.setText(names[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mCallback.onImageClick(position);
            }
        });

        return item_view;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    public interface swipeAdapterCallback {
        void onImageClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Then in your activity what you do is implement this interface and handle the onClick in the onImageClick function like so

```
    @Override
    public void onImageClick(int position) {
        //handle intents and launching activities here.
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                Log.d("Exercise","Dumbell Press");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,exampleAcitivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.d("Exercise","Deadlift!");
                break;
            case 3:
                Log.d("Exercise","Squats");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Since this block of code will be inside your Activity class creating intents and starting new activities handling result from these actitivities become very simple